# TKinter and JSON

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I'm looking for a resource to learning me how to connect TKinter and JSON 
Like take an input value (word) and search for that word in JSON then print out the result of the search 
by way, I have already the python application working through terminal but I want to go further step and build a GUI 
Thank you,

```
 import json                           #import the JSON module
from difflib import get_close_matches #difflib module provides classes and functions 
                                      #for comparing sequences
                                      #get_close_matches Return a list of 
                                      #the best “good enough” matches

data = json.load(open("data.json"))   #load JSON to python dictionary  

def translate(w): 
    w = w.lower()                     #change the input to lower case
    if w in data:                     #first scenario check if the word exist in the dictionary, if exist load the data
        return data[w]
    elif w.title() in data:           #When the user inputs a proper noun
        return data[w.title()]        #returns the definition of names that start with a capital letter
    elif w.upper() in data:           #definition of acronyms
        return data[w.upper()]
    elif len(get_close_matches(w, data.keys())) > 0: #second scenario compare the word and get the best match
         #ask the user if the result of matching what is looking for 
         YN = input("Did you mean %s instead? Enter y if yes or n if no:" % get_close_matches(w, data.keys())[0])
         if YN == "y":
            return data[get_close_matches(w, data.keys())[0]]
         elif YN == "n":
            return "The word doesn't exist. Please double check it."
         else:
            return "We didn't understand your entry."
    #third scenario the word not match or can't found
    else: 
        return "The word doesn't exsit. Please double check it."


word = input("Enter word: ") 

#in some cases the word have more than one definition so we need to make the output more readable 
output = translate(word)
if type(output) == list:
    for item in output:
        print(item)
else:
    print(output)
```

Comment: please fix the formatting of your question

Comment: I fixed, thanks for the note

Comment: There are several tkinter tutorials out there. Pick one and work through it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it!

1. Sketch some pictures of what your current program would look like if it had a GUI.

   - Would "Did you mean %s instead?" be a popup box?
   - Would you have a list of all the known words?
2. Build the UI using `tkinter`.
3. Connect the UI up to the functions in your program. (You do have those, don't you?)

Your program isn't quite ready yet, since you are doing stuff like using `input` inside your functions. Rework it so that it makes sense to have these outside your functions, then it'll probably be ready.

Comment: +1 : switching from CLI (Command Line Interface) to GUI (Graphical User Interface) requires some preliminary work to clarify how your app will interact with the user. Then (and only then) you will be able to convert your data/event flow into a set of widgets and callbacks

Comment: @sciroccorics Well, if you wrote the program "right" in the first place, then you reduce (or, in some cases, remove) the preliminary work required to convert it from one interface to another.